# Typecasting 2 Structures with Different Number of Variables

Tags: c, struct, casting

Here is the program in question:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct x{
    int i1;
    int i2;
    char ch1[8];
    char ch2[8];
};

struct y{
    long long int f1;
    char f2[18];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct x * myX;
    struct y * myY;
    myX = malloc(sizeof(struct x));
    myX->i1 = 4096;
    myX->i2 = 4096;
    strcpy(myX->ch1,"Stephen ");
    strcpy(myX->ch2,"Goddard");
    myY = (struct y *) myX;
    printf("myY->f1 = %llx\n", myY->f1);
    printf("myY->f2 = %s\n", myY->f2);
}
```

and here is the output:

```
myY -> f1 = 100000001000
myY -> f2 = Stephen Goddard
```

My question is how does this typecasting work?  I don't understand the output for f1.  4096 is 100000000000 in binary and 1000 in hex, so is it combining i1 and i2 into the one long long int?  If so, why does it combine in this way?  Does the structure being cast just look for similar variables and try to cram them all into one variable?  How does this process work?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `strcpy(myX->ch1,"Stephen ");` copies 9 `char` into a place for 8 `char`.  Go directly to UB Jail. Do not collect $200.

Comment: This depends on the memory layout. Let's inspect(memory dump) struct x.

Comment: "Stephen " is only 8 chars.  How do you inspect memory dump?

Answer (score 1):

This code causes undefined behaviour. C has a rule called *strict aliasing* . To paraphrase it, the standard doesn't define what happens if you write via an `int` expression and read via a `long long` expression.

Traditionally most compilers would "just do it" , i.e. it would write the two `int`s into those two memory locations, and then read enough bytes for a `long long` out of the same location, and hope it all made sense (which it usually did, since modern systems are such that every possible bit-pattern does represent a valid number).

However some compilers optimize the step out entirely because they know about the strict aliasing rule.

A further consideration is that there could be padding in between `i1` and `i2` etc., however you could verify that there is none by using the `offsetof` macro or a `sizeof` check before proceeding.

To do what you want in a well-defined manner you can either use `memcpy` or use a union, e.g.:

```
union xy
{
    struct x x;
    struct y y; 
};

union xy *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);
ptr->x.i1 = 4096;
ptr->x.i2 = 4096;
printf("%llx\n", (unsigned long long)ptr->y.f1);
```

If your system has unpadded 2's complement (all modern systems do), and no padding between members of your structs, and 32-bit int, and 64-bit long long, and big-endian int, then 4096 is `00 00 10 00` in hex, so the 8-byte block is `00 00 10 00 00 00 10 00` which is `0x100000001000` as you see in your output. Actually it comes out the same in little-endian too.

Note, `%llx` is for printing `unsigned long long`, it causes undefined behaviour to use it with a signed `long long` however all compilers that I know of will "work anyway". To be strictly correct I have added in a cast. (Consider changing your struct members to be `unsigned int` and `unsigned long long` to avoid issues with sign bits).